Best approach to have 2 domains at the same website ( my case is different ) read it
I have a problem so I decided to create two domains and redirect some of my users from google search results straight to the second domain by their geo location.
The Problem :
My problem is that my religion country is filtering my domain on dns layer every 6 months. I have a ecommerce site which selling sexual things. Since I'm getting all my traffic through google search,  I need to change my domain in search console every 6 month and this proccess is taking so much time for google to change my domain in result and get back to the previus rank.
What I need to do ?
I need to have two domains on a single wordpress website and redirect my country users straightly from search results to the second domain, so with this approach, my main domain will stay in results and the second domain will be filtered and it's easy to replace the filtered domain, so I don't lose my rank.
What I did so far? :
I've pointed my both domains to the website and create a seperate robots.txt for my second domain (via some custom config in nginx) and set noindex, nofollow meta tag in headers as well to all my second domain pages (using some custom php code) and implemented a 302 redirect in cloudflare to redirect users based their geo location to the second domain.
What's the result ? :
My current setup is working fine and it's redirecting users to the second domain, but the problem is since I've implemented this I'm experiencing a lot of click drops (2K click drops in 5 days) and it's going down, So I think somehow google knows I'm redirecting users and since it's not allowed to crawl the destination google thinks I'm cloaking or something else that I don't know about. But but the problem is click drops!
What other options do I have ?
Another approach is to allow google to crawl and index the second domain but set canonical url to the main domain
but I'm not sure if allowing crawl is enough or I should allow crawling, index and follow at the same time for the second domain and set canonical url to main domain as well, clear for me is crawling is enough or I should allow all ( crawl, index, follow ) for setting canonical to the main domain
I need your help with this :
I need you guys to help me, I don't have any other option I need to setup 2 domains for my website and redirect my country users to the second domain
What do you offer ? and What I did so far is enough ?
What's the reason of my click drops ? does google knows I'm redirecting users? since I'm sure google doesn't have any bots in my country to know it
How can I implement this setup in the best way to not penalty or any click drop and reach my goal which is redirecting my country users to another domain straightly from google search result
I've searched a lot and I couldn't find anything that helps me with this implementation.

Redirecting visitors based on country is totally acceptable, provided that you do the same for everyone (BOTS and USERS). If you show a page to a USER that is different from the one the BOT sees, that's the definition of CLOAKING. Search engines, and Google in particular, will penalize your rankings for this.

Placing NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW header tags is telling bots to remove the page(s) from the search results. Once removed, your rankings will naturally drop as the page(s) in question will no longer show.

Also, having two websites showing exactly the same content will get you a DUPLICATE penalty, lowering your results even further. You can minimize this by implementing canonical tags.

You have already de ided what to do. Perhaps you should be asking how to solve the problem rather than fix your solution. Please tour the help, this site works best with one question at a time.

@LuisAlbertoBarandiaran FYI, The myth of the duplicate content penalty
